How can I convert an email thread into a xml stream?
I would like to convert an email thread into a xml stream with the below format:
    <emails>
    <email index="1">
    <email_attr>
    These are the attributes (from, to, date, subject) of the 1st email
    </email_attr>
    <email_content>
    This is the content of the 1st email
    </email_content>
    </email>
    <email index="2">
    <email_attr>
    These are the attributes (from, to, date, subject) of the 2nd email
    </email_attr>
    <email_content>
    This is the content of the 2nd email
    </email_content>
    </email>
    ...
    </emails>

I tried 2 methods
1- Using the corresponding eml file. But the format differs between gmail / outlook and between languages. It is too complicated to take into account all the scenarios.
2- Using gmail APIs but forwarded emails would be counted as a unique message. The API doesn't manage to isolate each message from the forwarded thread.
